# Duplicated bullets with unordered list in UITextView using attribute of NSHTMLTextDocumentType

Tags: html, ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm displaying some HTML content in an `UITextView`. The content has bullet points. Those bullets are created with an unordered list (`<ul>`) but every bullet is being duplicated.

[image]

I create the **`NSAttributedString`** like

```
let contentHTML = ...

guard let data = contentHTML.data(using: .utf8) else {
    return
}

let attributedOptions: [String: AnyObject] = [
    NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType as AnyObject,
    NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSNumber(value: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
]

textView.attributedText = try! NSAttributedString(data: data, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
```

Why are the bullets points duplicated?
Any thoughts?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

The HTML content is something like

```
<p>Let’s take a quick look.</p><br/><ul><br/><li>lksdfjalsdjlajf</li><br/><li>lasdkjflaksjdf</li><br/><li>...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did some tests and I noticed what was causing the issue. Basically, every new line (`\n` or `<br>`) between  `<ul>` or `<li>` in an `UITextView` will create an extra bullet.

One workaround can be replacing the `<br/>` to empty string:

```
contentHTML = contentHTML.replacingOccurrences(of: "</li><br/><li>", with: "</li><li>")
contentHTML = contentHTML.replacingOccurrences(of: "<ul><br/><li>", with: "<ul><li>")
contentHTML = contentHTML.replacingOccurrences(of: "</li><br/></ul>", with: "</li></ul>")
```

**Result:**

[image]